# MPAndroidchart set mark decoration on chart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

How can i set an icon on the graph, connected to a data point,
The icon should follow the data entry point.
I tried using a customized marker, but i can only add one type of MarkerView.

I want to set different icon markers on the graph, to specify different
events happening.

Is there a way to specify or set different markers for highlighting?
Or is it not a good way to set more permanent "decoration" icons on the chart.